# How can I refresh a table that contains JQuery mobile buttons without losing formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table

I have created a function that generates a table of JQuery mobile buttons; using JavaScript (This is called in the document ready function), using the following code - this works fine:

```
function renderButtons() {

console.log(coaches);
var coachButtonsHTML = "";

coachButtonsHTML += "<table align='center' class='full_width_table'>" +
          "<tr>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='0' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach A " + "(" + coaches[0].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='1' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach B " + "(" + coaches[1].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='2' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach C " + "(" + coaches[2].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "</tr>" +
          "<tr>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='3' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach D " + "(" + coaches[3].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='4' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach E " + "(" + coaches[4].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "<td class='cellpadding'><div id='5' data-role='button' data-position-to='window' data-mini='true' onclick='coachSelect(this.id)'>Coach F " + "(" + coaches[5].value + ")" + "</div></td>" +
          "</tr>" +
          "</table>";

$('#coach_buttons').append(coachButtonsHTML).trigger('create');
}
```

The problem is that I am updating the values within the buttons in a different function, and trying to update the buttons by calling the render function - `renderButtons();`. This leads the problem of having two sets of buttons.

So I tried using this line of code to "update" the table:

```
$('#coach_buttons').append(coachButtonsHTML).trigger('update');
```

Using this code renders the button values, however there is no formatting (its just text no button).

Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Comment: Check out how to use cookies or localStorage..

Comment: Try (enhancewithin) if you use 1.4> -- http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

Comment: @Tasos I tried this and it makes duplicates of the buttons, also they don't have any formatting on them still.

Comment: @user26409021 I have a vague idea of how to use localStorage, although how would this help me in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using the following line of code -

```
$('#coach_buttons').html(coachButtonsHTML).trigger('create');
```

This means that it doesn't create duplicates and keeps the formatting as it replaces the html, whereas the other one added to it.

Comment: there you go, you learn something new everyday. Append appends new data to the old, It doesn't replace the old. So it might be worth emptying the existing HTML before you create it. Put this before what you have above --  ($('#coach_buttons').empty();)